# List of Map Convert to JSON

Tags: json, dictionary, gson

I have a `List<Map<String, Object>>` when printed on screen `logger.trace(responseMap);` is below:

```
[{1ST REWARDS=null, 2ND REWARDS=null, 3RD REWARDS=null, RESELLER - FEES(4pct)=null, RESELLER - COMMISSION=null, 4TH AWARD=null}]
```

But upon convert into Json using code

```
new Gson().toJson(responseMap);
```

The output become:

```
[{}]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your values are `null`. You can put values in there and see if that changes your output.  Given the nulls, your output is expected.  From the [gson docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support) --

> The default behaviour that is implemented in Gson is that null object
>   fields are ignored.

If you want the nulls too appear in the json output, add `serializeNulls` to your `GsonBuilder`.

```
Gson gsonWithNulls = new GsonBuilder()
    .serializeNulls()
    .create();
```